# Can Nook Read Kobo Books and Vise Versa?

Tags: kobo, nook, adobe-digital-editions

I've been a Kindle user for years, but have had some frustration with Amazon lately and am thinking I want to diversify a bit by buying some other eReader. If I understand correctly, both Nook and Kobo use Adobe Digital Editions. If that is true, does that mean I should be able to load books bought from Barnes and Noble on a Kobo (or books bought from Kobo on a Nook)? Kobo [seems to allude to this](https://help.kobo.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017814074-Add-eBooks-with-Adobe-Digital-Editions-#:%7E:text=Add%20eBooks%20with%20Adobe%20Digital%20Editions.%201%20Step,Common%20ADE%20errors%20and%20solutions.%20%20More%20items), especially since, unless I'm missing something, the Nook store and Kobo store are the only two major Adobe Digital Editions options. On the other hand, I haven't found anyone one specifically speaking to Kobo/Nook compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Both NOOK and Kobo have a variety of book formats in common, such EPUB and Adobe PDF. Kobo [can use Adobe Digital Editions](https://help.kobo.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017814074-Add-eBooks-with-Adobe-Digital-Editions-), but [Barnes and Noble states,](https://help.barnesandnoble.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1498/%7E/nook-books-from-barnes-%26-noble-on-kobo-ereader) "NOOK Books from Barnes & Noble **cannot** be read on your Kobo eReader." However, B&N states the converse works, i.e., [transferring ebooks from Kobo to NOOK](https://help.barnesandnoble.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2808/related/1/session/). It *is* possible to read DRM NOOK books on Kobo by the [legally-questionable removal of DRM](https://epubor.com/how-to-read-nook-books-on-kobo.html).

That said, for books *without* DRM, such as the many public-domain offerings on [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/), [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/), and publishers of copyright-protected, but *not* DRM locked, ebooks, such as [Baen Books](https://www.baen.com/), texts can be transferred between devices using software such as the excellent [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/) application.

Using Calibre or other tool, it's also possible to change the format of a book, such as Kindle's MOBI to NOOK and Kobo EPUB, or *vice-versa*. (Note that PDF is somewhat a dead-end: while it is easy to convert documents to PDF, going from PDF to another format is not always successful.)